# Rails views template outside of versioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got versioning API which means all controllers are located in `api/v1/controller_name.rb` which determines the location of the views inside `views/api/v1/controller_name/show.html.erb`. How to define location globally to skip `api/v1/` part and have templates in:

`views/controller_name/show.html.erb`

instead of:

`views/api/v1/controller_name/show.html.erb`

EDIT:

index and new action inside of controller:

```
  def index
    @properties = Property.all
  end

  def new
    @portfolio = Portfolio.new
  end
```

Comment: Why do your API controllers render HTML?

Comment: By API I mean controller versions, I thought that's obvious.

Comment: If you have an app that has an API and also a back office in rails, for example, you would create an `APIController` and all controllers part of the API would inherit from it and only those controllers need to be versioned. They don't render views. The back office controllers inherit from `ApplicationController` and they are responsible for rendering the views which don't have to be versioned. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to how to render views in a different directory you should be able to just pass the full path to `render` as the `views/` directory is in the search path for views. So something like:

```
class ApiController
  def show
    render 'api_controller/show'
  end
end
```

Comment: But where should I pass it? inside of controller?

Comment: Yes, in the method for the API route inside of the controller. I updated my answer with a more complete example.